# I can't get this picture in the background of my div

Tags: css, background

Can someone point me in the right direction? I don't see why I can't get the black_bottom.png as background in rounded corners.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

html,
body {
  color: #444141;
  font-family: 'trebuchet ms' !important;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #eaeade;
}

.justyParagraph {
  text-align: justify;
}

a img {
  border: 0;
}

.clearer {
  clear: both;
}

.rounded_corners {
  background: url(../images/box/black_bottom.png) no-repeat left bottom;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 380px;
  border: 2px solid #4e4b4b;
  height: 450px;
}

div#blockdark {
  height: 517px;
  left: 450px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
  z-index: 1000000;
  width: 360px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="blockdark">
  <div class="rounded_corners">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

This is an example, maybe it has something to do with the JavaScript for `rounded_corners` class?

[http://www.coldcharlie.nl/test](http://www.coldcharlie.nl/test/)

Comment: Can you load the image alone? This would diagnose many configuration errors. A online demo would be helpful too.

Comment: Can you verify that the image is in correct location relative to the css file?

Comment: Try setting that image to a fully qualified url, with domain and everything, to prove the css works - then go after the problem in with your configutation.

Comment: Is the hosting a Windows or Linux box?  On Linux boxes, all file references are case sensitive, so capitals do make a difference.

Comment: somebody please edit the question to add formatting to CSS

Comment: `http://www.coldcharlie.nl/test/`  this is not having the background image attr in round corner css!!. Am i on the right path Chris?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure that `../images/box/black_bottom.png` is the path from your *stylesheet* to the image file.  Everything else looks correct, but people don't always realize that paths are relative to the css file and not the page that includes it.

Try an absolute URL there and see if it appears then.  If it does, you know your relative URL isn't right.

Comment: If you look at the style info in Firebug and hover your cursor over that "url()" expression, it'll either show you the image, or it won't. If it doesn't, that means that the URL is bad.

Answer (score 1):

EITHER:

Your image doesn't exist at this relative path: ../images/box/black_bottom.png.

OR:

Your image is blank.

OR:

Your image has more blank space in the image's left bottom corner than the dimensions of your div.rounded_corners, and therefore the background image "overshoots" your div.

Answer (score 0):

HI...

This might give you something to have a look at...

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #mydiv{
        background-image:url('http://www.theregister.co.uk/Design/graphics/std/logo_414_80.png');
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">
<p>Mary had this little lamb...</p>
<p>Mary had this little lamb...</p>
<p>Mary had this little lamb...</p>
<p>Mary had this little lamb...</p>
<p>Mary had this little lamb...</p>
<p>Mary had this little lamb...</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Just something to get you started.

Also, your div#blockdark doesn't validate - use #blockdark instead...

(The id should be unique, so tag type doesn't matter)